# How to put the average in the last table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

this my code and it increases always when i have an evaluation, in the end it shows the grade, but, the average always stays after the grade. I wanted to know how I do it to put it at the end.

```
   <% @registration.matrix.blocks.each do |block| %>
    <h5>Block: <%= block.description %></h5>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered shadow-sm">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>Discipline</th>
                <th>Assigned Fouls</th>
                <th>Test 1</th>
                <th>Test 2</th>
                <th>Test 3</th>
                <th>Test 4</th>
                <th>Test 5</th>
                <th>Test 6</th>
                <th>Test 7</th>
                <th>Test 8</th>
                <th>Final Test</th>
                <th>Average</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% block.disciplines.distinct.each do |discipline| %>

            <tr>
                <td><%= discipline.name %></td>
                <td>
                    <%= number_of_absences(current_user, discipline) %>
                </td>
                <% discipline.evaluations.each do |evaluation| %>
                    <td><%= Evaluate.get_evaluate(current_user.id, evaluation.id).present? ? Evaluate.get_evaluate(current_user.id, evaluation.id).note : '0,0' %></td>
                <% end %>
                <td><%= get_media(current_user, discipline) %></td>
            </tr>
            <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<% end %>
</div>
```

[Image to see the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke88p.png)
So I would like to know how I fix the error, for example I put the grade 10, it divides by 8 as I programmed, but the average that is 10/8 since 10 was the only grade that assigns, it gets 1,25 however the average is on the side and not in the end, as I do to put in the end in the table "average"

Comment: Its difficult for someone who doesn't understand (I guess) spanish to make sense of what is happening in the code and in the image, can you put an image with english words ?

Comment: I think you should build the full table following a different strategy. So you don't miss any <td>

Answer (score 0):

If the question is *how to align the average value under the Average table header?* the answer is that you have to put as many `td` as needed in order to align it there, otherwise I didn't understand the question :-)

Comment: it's portuguese brazilian.in the code u can see the english names!